# Как запустить qt assistant после установки на linux

Tags: linux, qt

Установил qt assistant:
sudo apt install qt5-assistant

Где его теперь найти. То есть как мне его запустить.

Comment: `$ dpkg -L имя.пакета | grep /bin`

Comment: "где находится" и "как запустить" это очень разные вопросы.

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось.

Answer (score -1):

Ниже приведены некоторые из папок, которые могут содержать исполняемый файл Qt Assistant:

- /opt/Qt/Tools/QtAssistant/bin/qhelpviewer
- /usr/lib/qt<версия>/bin/qhelpviewer
- /usr/local/Qt<версия>/bin/qhelpviewer

Обратите внимание, что "<версия>" соответствует версии Qt, установленной в вашей системе.

Подробнее тут еще расписал - https://qaa-engineer.ru/gde-nahoditsya-qt-assistant-posle-ustanovki-na-linux/

После установки Qt Assistant на Linux можно его запустить, выполнив следующие шаги:

1. Откройте терминал.
2. Введите команду `assistant`, которая запустит Qt Assistant.
3. Если путь к программе `assistant` не настроен в переменной среды PATH, вы можете указать полный путь к программе. Например: `/путь/к/Qt/assistant`.

После выполнения этих шагов Qt Assistant должен запуститься и открыть окно справки.

Comment: [Почему публикация ответов, созданных GPT и ChatGPT, недопустима?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12247/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-gpt-%d0%b8-chatgpt-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0)